# Model faces seem to appear in a random area after extending

Tags: modeling, extrude

Sorry if this has been asked before.

When I extend a face or point, some of the pieces appear as if they have been ripped/removed from the model and randomly placed in the work area, but can't figure out what is causing it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying but the small part on the left must actually be the real mesh, and the one on the right but be it's mirrored image, so bring back the left part on the right, and enable the modifier Clipping option to avoid the problem?

Comment: The pieces are part of the mesh - I can't access them with the mouse. I cant select them nor move them at all. The only way to bring them back to place is to undo the work all the way back until they go back where they belong.